# Array in Monotouch NSUserDefaults

Tags: arrays, set, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults

Does anyone know how to store an array in Monotouch NSUserDefaults?

One possible method:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults["Array"] = new NSObject();
```

But how do I turn an array or list into an NSObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Monotouch.Foundation.NSArray. You will probably initialize it with static FromNSObjects().